# Weird controls when using Python as interface

Tags: python, c, interface, keyboard, arduino

I'm implementing Python (2.7.9) as an interface between my Arduino with a joystick and a couple of buttons and my Linux machine to control Megaman on an emulator. The joystick does x/y movements and the buttons do fire and jump. My code receives a string formatted as (X_Y_FIRE_JUMP), and parses out the values to then see what it should input on the keyboard by using the [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput) library.

One weird bug is happening though: Whenever I move to the right, even without pressing either one of the buttons, Megaman fires frenetically. I've checked my serial output to see if this was hardware sided, and it isn't; the serial string being received is clean as it should be looking something like this "[X>510]_[Y~510]_k_t". So, the X is telling it to move to the right, Y doesn't really do anything, k is telling it not to jump and 
t is telling it not to fire. Why am I nonetheless getting sketchy unexpected firing **only** when I move to the right?

Python Code:

```
import serial
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard


control = PyKeyboard()


def getxy():
    while True:
        try:
            ab = arduino.readline()
            a, b, c, d = ab.split("_")
            a = int(a)
            a = a - 512
    # This is pure jiggery-pokery and apple sauce. The joystick controller is
    # totally kaput (#german) and I didn't want to mess with the wiring (damn
    # color wires. Don't touch this, it will hurt your family.)
            b = int(b)
            b = (b - 512) * -1
            return a, b, c, d
        except Exception:
            continue
        break


def procxy():
    x, y, s, j = getxy()
    mov = ""
    if (x > 100):
        mov = mov + "r"
    if (x < -100):
        mov = mov + "l"
    if (y > 100):
        mov = mov + "u"
    if (y < -100):
        mov = mov + "d"
    if ("f" in s):
        mov = mov + "f"
    if ("j" in j):
        mov = mov + "j"
    return mov


def doshot(instr):
    if ("f" in instr):
        control.press_key('z')
    if ("f" not in instr):
        control.release_key('z')


def dojump(instr):
    if ("j" in instr):
        control.press_key('s')
    if ("j" not in instr):
        control.release_key('s')


def domove():
    movstr = procxy()
    doshot(movstr)
    dojump(movstr)
    while ("r" in movstr):
        control.press_key(control.right_key)
        movstr = procxy()
        doshot(movstr)
        dojump(movstr)
    control.release_key(control.right_key)
    while ("l" in movstr):
        control.press_key(control.left_key)
        movstr = procxy()
        doshot(movstr)
        dojump(movstr)
    control.release_key(control.left_key)


try:
    arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 9600)
except:
    print ("Failed to connect on /dev/ttyACM0")
while True:
    x, y, s, j = getxy()
    domove()
    print ("X = {0}\nY = {1}".format(x, y))
```

Arduino C code:

```
int y = 0;
int x = 0;
int fire = 0;
int jump = 0;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  y = analogRead(A0);
  x = analogRead(A1);
  fire = analogRead(A2);
  jump = analogRead(A3);
  String out = "";
  out.concat(x);
  out.concat("_");
  out.concat(y);
  if(fire > 900)
  {
    out.concat("_");
    out.concat("f");
  }
  else
  {
    out.concat("_");
    out.concat("t");
  }
  if (jump > 900)
  {
    out.concat("_");
    out.concat("j");
  }
  else
  {
    out.concat("_");
    out.concat("k");
  }
  out.concat("\n");
  Serial.print(out);
}
```

Comment: Why analogRead instead of digitalRead for button? How do you check your serial output ?

Comment: @Ôrel I'm using analog read because my buttons were being kinky and on-and-offing. Serial output is being checked for on the first line of the try on the GetXY function.

Comment: What I mean, is how are you sure the output is good, base on our code, you should receive several line on a second. Have you  check each received lines ?.

Comment: @Ôrel I have a serial monitor open during testing and I can see what's going on. There's nothing changing on the part pertaining to fire command on the serial string on the input to the Python code but either way when I walk right (and only right) I fire like crazy, which makes no sense to me really.

Comment: Have you try to write a simple prog using PyKeyboard and doing several moves without reading input to see where is the problem ?

Comment: Not really, good idea, ill try that to see although I don't think that's the issue. Before I implemented fire actions to my code it didn't do that, so u really think the cause to it is code related on my part.

Comment: If you have not doubt about the data send by arduino the problem can be into your code, into your keyboard lib or in the game. Doing the test prog you will show if the problem is your python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error, as it turned out, was due to a bad resistor causing the Arduino to have a slight overvoltage on it's analog ports and thus causing interference. Since the joystick is analog the issue would only happen when that particular axis was more active and thus the particularity of the bug happening only when the character moved to the right.